# Where can I find a good introduction to papercraft?

Tags: papercraft

I recently stumbled upon the [papercraft](/questions/tagged/papercraft) tag and found the answer to one of the tagged questions very interesting.  I would like to try making some stuff for theoretical use in a 3.X game, but I have never heard of papercraft before and, though I now have heard you can do it by hand, I don't really know where to start.  Where can I find a good introduction to the subject and some basic tutorials/projects to get started with.  I'm not interested in making any financial commitment to this yet, so the tutorials/intro/etc should be free and not require too much in the way of materials.  Obviously some paper will be required, but if there are special tools or inks or paper or anything, an intro that works without me having to go buy that stuff would be good.  I have some extra sheets of cardstock lying around, a papercutter, scissors, and a moddeling knife.  Also pencils.

Answer (score 6):

The best introduction to papercraft is to just start trying it. It's an uncomplicated hobby and best learned by fumbling along and improving through tactile experience. The worst that can happen is you'll wreck the printout and learn something, and print a fresh one out to try again with lessons learned.

Mistakes just aren't costly, and there are lots of free PDF models out there, so it's worth diving in heedlessly and making a few without worrying about doing it right the first time. Even a "wrecked" model can teach you something, and you can bull ahead and finish it anyway just for the learning experience. Your second will be an order of magnitude better for the mistakes you make with the first.

Topically for RPGs, Wizards of the Coast has (had, this is the archive) [a page full of fantasy-themed papercraft](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111213300/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/fpm/archive). These are fairly pretty models, and free is always nice. **The first PDF there is a good general introduction** to the tools,<sup>1</sup> skills, and techniques for building functional papercraft models. Pick one of the models further down the page to be your first foray. I'd suggest the *Three Story City Wall* or the *Timber Hoarding* as a first model, since they're boxes with a few interesting bits and that will give you the basic skills. After that, get as complicated as you feel like!

It's a hobby that isn't punishing if you're unskilled, so just start, and have fun. It does reward skill gained though, so the more attention to detail you put in (and learn where it's worth putting in), the nicer the resulting models will be.

1. You can get fancy with tools and materials, but for my money, a sharp X-Acto knife (or competitor), a cutting mat, and school-kid gluesticks are plenty, plus maybe toothpicks for spreading glue in awkward angles. (Glue sticks have the advantage of not over-wetting the paper too.) Most instructions suggest a metal ruler, but any straightedge will do if you're careful not to slice it up. If you're going to cheap out on everything else, spend on the cutting mat — they make cutting smoother, more controlled, and safer, giving you the best bang for your beginner's buck.